# In OLS, when absolute value of the coefficient of a independent variable is large, does it mean this independent variable is more important?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, importance

Assume there is no multicollinearity and each feature in data **X** has been standardized to zero mean and unit variance.

Comment: If you assume that your predictor variables in X are independent, and if you have them standardized to have zero mean and unit variance, then the answer is yes. The larger the coefficient (in absolute value) the more weight it has on the prediction of the response variable, so the more important it is.